# How to re-render a component on an event of an another unrelated component

Tags: reactjs, react-context

I have a `React` app & component structure looks like below

productsList.component.ts

```
export const ProductsListComponent = () => {

const [category, setcategory] = useState("retail");
const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);   
const categorySelectHandler = (selectedCategory:string) => {
  setcategory(selectedCategory);
}

useEffect(() => {
 getProductsByCategory(category).then((products) => {
  setProducts(products);
   }
  });
  }, [category]);
  
return (
  <ProductsContext.Provider value={{products:products}}>
  <CategorySelector onCategorySelected={categorySelectHandler} products={products}></CategorySelector>
  <Product products={products}></Product>
 </ProductsContext.Provider>)
```

product.component.ts

```
export const Product = () => {
  const ctx = useContext(ProductsContext);
  
  const [products, setProducts] = useState(ctx.Products);
    
  return (
  <>
  { products.map((product) => {
  return ( 
   <div> 
    <b> {product.name} </b>
    <i> {product.price} </b>
   }
  }
 </<>
```

categorySelector.component.ts

```
const CategorySelector: React.FC <CategorySelectorProps> = ({
onCategorySelected,
products
}) => {

const ctx = useContext(ProductsContext);


 
  const quantityHandler = (e) => {
    const quantity =  e.target.value()
    //doing some calculations here & updating the products array
    ctx.products = []; //new array
    
  }

return ( 
  <div>
  {
    //needing to display the products name here some business reason
    products.map(product => <p> product.name </p> 
  }
  <input type="text" onChange={quantityHandler} name="Quantity" />
    </div>
)};

export default CategorySelector;
```

> Here `onChange` event of the textbox in CategorySelector component, I
> am doing some BL calculations & updating the `products` array & on
> this **I need to re-render the Product Component without re-rendering
> the CategorySelector component.**

Thanks!

Comment: Would it be possible for you to remove the useEffect on the parent component and not pass the products to the Product component. But instead directly handle the event in the Product component itself?  Passing events from sibling to sibling instead of sibling -> parent -> other sibling.

Comment: @CasperKuethe No, this will break/affect the other functionality as desired

Comment: Maybe take a look at React memo components explained in [this article](https://linguinecode.com/post/prevent-re-renders-react-functional-components-react-memo) I think this would fit your case

Comment: @CasperKuethe, No React memo won't. Because in my case, the `products` is passed to both `CategorySelector` & `Product`